# What is wrong with the browser Surf?

Tags: browser

So I downloaded Surf from the Ubuntu repository and compiled it from source. But every time I launch it I only get a blank white screen. Any suggestions would be helpful. Maybe I'm missing some dependencies or something like that?

Comment: Run it from a terminal, and look for any error messages. Why did you need to compile it from source, rather than `apt-get install` it?

Comment: @Jos, because it suckless, I want to be able to patch and change the source code :) (However, I don't know if it's possible when installed via package manager)

Answer (score 2):

It's minimalistic.

You need to press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> (by default) to open the URL prompt, then type it in and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>. Alternatively, you can press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> to get the URL from your clipboard.